# VMWare issue with Mavericks

Tags: vmware-fusion

I was using a OS X Mountain lion on my Mac and changed to Mavericks. I had created a VMware partition for windows OS also in that Macbook. After installing Mavericks, VMware says not compatible with Mavericks. what has to be done to retrieve my windows functionality. I have VNware Fusion 3.1.1 on my laptop.

Please guide.

Regards
ss

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe SuperUser would be a good place to post this. Since at SO it's mostly code related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the current Version of VMWare Fusion.

Comment: I am using VMWare Fusion on Mountain Lion with several Windows VMs in VMWare files and bootcamp partition. You can only be sure, if you try it. Download a demo....